# Bazel doesn't build ios mediapipe examples

Tags: ios, build, bazel, mediapipe

I tried to build HandTrackingExample and get this error

> ERROR:
> /Users/air/Documents/mediapipe/mediapipe/examples/ios/handtrackinggpu/BUILD:34:16:
> ProcessEntitlementsFiles
> mediapipe/examples/ios/handtrackinggpu/HandTrackingGpuApp_entitlements.entitlements
> failed (Exit 1): plisttool failed: error executing command
> bazel-out/host/bin/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/tools/plisttool/plisttool
> ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped)
>
> Note: The failure of target
> @build_bazel_rules_apple//tools/plisttool:plisttool (with exit code 1)
> may have been caused by the fact that it is running under Python 2
> instead of Python 3. Examine the error to determine if that appears to
> be the problem. Since this target is built in the host configuration,
> the only way to change its version is to set --host_force_python=PY3,
> which affects the entire build.
>
> If this error started occurring in Bazel 0.27 and later, it may be
> because the Python toolchain now enforces that targets analyzed as PY2
> and PY3 run under a Python 2 and Python 3 interpreter, respectively.
> See https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7899 for more
> information.

I tried build with `--host_force_python=PY3 and PY2` but error the same

The link that is given in the error did not find a solution to your problem. How do I build a project correctly?

Comment: I would build with options `--verbose_failures --verbose_explanations=true -s ` to get more logs about the actual error.

Answer (score -3):

Try it

```
$ brew install python
$ sudo ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
$ pip3 install --user six
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.